# Drawing an image on a UIView, and making a transparent hole to see the UIView underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I have a UIView I'm trying to put together which will be layered above another view. This new view needs to have a fully transparent hole in it. I've attached a screenshot of what it is I'm trying to accomplish (checkerboard pattern is the underlying UIView that will be adding this new UIView as a sublayer, red is a UIImage).

[image: Black transparent is UIView, red is UIImage]

I have the following code that will render the black background with the hole in the center:

```
- (void)
drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGRect boxRect = CGRectMake(_location.x - (kPointRadius/2), _location.y - (kPointRadius/2), kPointRadius, kPointRadius);

  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath
                        bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.layer.frame.size.width, self.layer.frame.size.height)
                        cornerRadius:0];

  UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath
                              bezierPathWithRoundedRect:boxRect
                              cornerRadius:kPointRadius];
  [path appendPath:circlePath];
  [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

  CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  fillLayer.path = path.CGPath;
  fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
  fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  fillLayer.borderWidth = 5.0;
  fillLayer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
  fillLayer.opacity = 0.7;
  [self.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];
}
```

However, when I add an image to that and use `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"testimg" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];` to add the image, the image covers the hole.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm stumped.

**EDIT:** I'm now able to get it almost there. I can get everything I need EXCEPT the image layered on top of the black, 90% opaque background is also at 90% opacity.

```
CGRect boxRect = CGRectMake(
                              _location.x - (kPointRadius/2),
                              _location.y - (kPointRadius/2),
                              kPointRadius,
                              kPointRadius);

  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath
                        bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.layer.frame.size.width, self.layer.frame.size.height) cornerRadius:0];

  UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath
                              bezierPathWithRoundedRect:boxRect
                              cornerRadius:kPointRadius];
  [path appendPath:circlePath];
  [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimg"];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 57, 350, 230)];
  imageView.image = image;
  CGRect r = CGRectMake(self.layer.frame.origin.x, self.layer.frame.origin.y, self.layer.frame.size.width, self.layer.frame.size.height);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, NO, 0);
  CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextAddPath(c, CGPathCreateCopy(path.CGPath));

  CGContextEOClip(c);
  CGContextFillRect(c, r);
  UIImage* maskim = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  CALayer* mask = [CALayer layer];
  mask.frame = r;
  mask.contents = (id)maskim.CGImage;
  imageView.layer.mask = mask;
  self.layer.mask = mask;
  self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  self.layer.opacity = 0.8;
  [self.layer addSublayer:imageView.layer];
```

Comment: Instead of trying to draw a hole, I'd redraw the bottom image you're trying to show into a little circular UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: I'm now able to get it almost there. I can get everything I need EXCEPT the image layered on top of the black, 90% opaque background is also at 90% opacity.

Instead of setting its opacity, you could set the layer's background color to `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.9]`.